# Asymmetries in the DKW bound

Tags: quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function, bounds

Suppose I have $n$ i.i.d. samples $X_1,...,X_n$ drawn from a distribution with CDF $F$. We use the samples to form the empirical CDF:
$$F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{1}_{X_i\leq x}$$
The Dvoretzky–Kiefer–Wolfowitz inequality provide quantitative bounds for how close we are to the true CDF (i.e., how close $F$ is to $F_n$).  Specifically, for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\Pr\left(\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(x)-F(x)|>\epsilon\right)\leq 2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}$$
Here's my confusion: if we evaluate $F_n(x)$ on our *actual* data then
$F_n(X_1)=1/n$
but
$F_n(X_n)=1$
Therefore, the corresponding quantile ranges are asymmetric (for instance, the portion of the CDF band at $X_1$ is always larger than the band at $X_n$, since the latter "clips" more).

My question is: is there a symmetric version of the DKW inequality?  (Possibly I'm really asking "is there a symmetric definition of the empirical CDF with a corresponding DKW inequality?")

(If I had my druthers, I'd set $F_n(X_i)=(i-1)/(n-1)$, because that's the mode of the marginal distribution of the $i$-th quantile (i.e., the Beta distribution) and it's symmetric.  But I don't know what the corresponding pseudo-DKW bound should be.)